# How to integration test a TokenCache implementation?

Tags: .net, adal

I have created a subclass of TokenCache. How do I verify that it works? Meaning does it handle expired tokens properly? Can I make a token invalid programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

The only functionality you can manipulate in a custom ADAL cache is the persistence and loading of the cache blob- token specific logic like expiration based substitution are done by ADAL in its in-memory copy of the cache, and aren't affected by your implementation. If you want to take a look at a custom cache in action you can check out https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-desktop-msgraph-v2/, but again, it won't show you how to test functionality at the token entry level. The extensibility is designed to allow you to select your preferred storage technology, but the core token acquisition and lifetime remains under ADAL's control.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, does this mean that a expired token being returned by the cache will not cause any issues?

Comment: I am saying that it's not up to your implementation what gets returned by ADAL. Via events, you have an opportunity to do just in time reads from your storage and write them into the inmemory cache when the library is about to inspect it. If the content of your cache includes an access token meeting the requirements of the call to acquiretoken* causing the lookup, and the token is expired, ADAL will act accordingly and attempt to use  a refresh token and get a new access token. If the refresh token is also bad, you'll get an exception requiring you to repeat interactive auth; and so on.